# Floating point operations resulting in a number that is essentially zero

Tags: c++, math, floating-point

I'm doing some calculations that result in a value like {-0.707107, 9.61481e-017, 0.707107} when I'm expecting {-0.707107, 0, 0.707107}. Could that second component, while essentially zero, cause problems down the road? Should I do something about it? Using C++ doubles.

Comment: That really depends on the accuracy your application needs. Rounding errors can accumulate over time, only you know if it is acceptable for your application.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

That depends very much on what you intend to do down the road. :-) However, getting results that are very close to, but not exactly equal, to what the "mathematical" result should be, is something one must live with when using floating point numbers. A common solution is to define some "epsilon" value (say, `1e-10`) and accept an error of `epsilon` in all comparisons - so `x == y` would become `fabs(x - y) < epsilon`.

Comment: If you are working with computations that always result in a limited number of decimals (which you are apparently not, since your numbers seem very close to `sqrt(2)`), for instance monetary calculations, you should avoid float/double at all costs and either use a fixed precision data type (e.g. from the [GNU Multiple Precision Arithmetic Library](http://gmplib.org/)), or scale all your numbers up so that you can work with integers.

Answer (score 5):

They will only "cause problems" if you (a) are doing a numerically unstable calculation (you probably aren't) or (b) will later attempt to compare them using strict equality.  In general, you shouldn't "do something" about it, you should just make sure that your algorithm is not overly sensitive to a small amount of imprecision.

Answer (score 1):

Yes they could cause problems, when comparing with `0.` using `==`: that will return `false`. Such rounding errors may also accumulate, as @driis noted.

What you can do about this: instead of comparing using `==`, use a comparison that allows for round-off errors, and/or discard values that are below a reasonable threshold at appropriate points in the algorithm, depending on what you want to do with the values.

See any good book on numerical algorithms.

Answer (score 1):

You can only safely use == for comparing floats for certain values and even then only when you have assigned those values directly, you can't use it for the result of any calcualtion.

normally you define a function

```
bool isEqual(double a,double b) {
  return fabs(a-b) < 0.0000001; // depends on the precision of your application
}

bool isClose(double a,double b) {
  return fabs(a-b) < 0.001;
}
```